# FtpWebRequest ConnectionGroupName practise question

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I have a question about the `request.ConnectionGroupName`.
I know that I should use the same GroupnName for the same HOST URL as `MaxServicePointIdleTime` is 100 seconds where all requests whithin that GroupName gets recycled.

What I now wonder is if it is a good or bad practise to have different Groupnames for different `request.Method` for the SAME host if I show what I mean below:

`request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;   request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group1";
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile; request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group2";
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;   request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group3";`

Complete Code example for: **Ftp.UploadFile;**

```js
void uploadimage()
        {
            String sourceimage = "C:/ESD/image_2.jpg";
            Task<bool> task = FtpUploadFile(sourceimage);
            if (task.IsFaulted == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(task.Result.ToString());
            }
        }
        private Task closeRequestStreamAsync(Stream requestStream) { return Task.Run(() => { requestStream.Close(); }); }
        public async Task<bool> FtpUploadFile(string filename)
        {
            //if exception occurs we want to be able to close these
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            FtpWebRequest request = null;
            FileStream sourceStream = null;
            Stream requestStream = null;
            try
            {
                bool isimage = false; String ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif" || ext == ".bmp") { isimage = true; }

                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://someurl.com/Folder1/test1.jpg");
                request.UsePassive = true;
                if (isimage == true) { request.UseBinary = true; } //for images
                if (isimage == false) { request.UseBinary = false; } //for text
                request.KeepAlive = true; //keep the connection open
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.ConnectionGroupName = "Group1";
                request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 4;

                //These are the credentials.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");


                sourceStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sourceStream.Length];
                await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                sourceStream.Close();

                requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
                await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //MPM  This is the call that takes the time     
                await closeRequestStreamAsync(requestStream);

                //response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                WebResponse responseWeb = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                response = (FtpWebResponse)responseWeb;
                if (response.StatusDescription.Contains("226"))
                {
                    //This means that we successfully have uploaded the file!
                }
                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errMSG = string.Format("Upload File failed, exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I did read this on: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.connectiongroupname?view=netframework-4.8` "Using connection groups can improve performance because this allows all of the requests for a user to reuse the connection authenticated with the user's credentials."

Comment: Does the above mean that one can use: `Ftp.UploadFile, Ftp.DownloadFile, Ftp.DeleteFile` for the same Groupname. - Or should I use different Groupnames for the methods? (Host and credentials are the same)